# Django project - Bad Request (400) on certain urls

Tags: python, django, heroku

This is first question here and I will try to follow the guidelines to the best of my understanding. ( Also, English is not my first language )

I made a little project using Django, a job search website and i'm running it with `DEBUG` set to `True` ( not advised I know, but I wanted to know the cause if anything went wrong )

The admin section and homepage ( and another one ) are working correctly, but the search page gives me a 400 error page. `Bad Request (400)`.
The only difference with the other working page is that the search contains a form. The "heroku logs" doesnt give more detail about the error. Any advice about where I should look for the cause of the problem ?

Everything works correctly locally, I only get the 400 error once it's pushed on heroku. Help ?

---

As requested, Here are the urls of the search page:

```
url(r'^search/$',search,name="job-search"),  #I use this to collect the search parameter
url(r'^search/(?P<domain>\w+)/(?P<level>\w+)/$',results,name="job-result"),  # **Where the 400 error happens** , this is the result page
```

Comment: well a 400 does not mean there is gonna be an error, that's why nothing is in the logs, you must have set the route incorrectly. Could you paste your urls ?

Comment: if you define ADMINS and you have setup MAIL properly, there is no need for Debug on live sites, you receive an email with the debug output.

Comment: Add your host to ```ALLOWED_HOSTS``` in the settings file.

Comment: Hi @schillingt , `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is already set to `['*']`

Comment: @PepperoniPizza I pasted the urls. Can you help ? I dont think there is a problem in there because everything is working fine locally.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your method has some decorator that prevents access to it, like: @ajax_required